# What is IDR_TYPELIB1?

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop

I can't find any good resources online about what this is. It's required in one of the steps for deploying a .NET assembly for use by COM, but there is no detail what it is or what it means.

As an example, here is something from the book I'm reading on Interop:

> Next you need to create a resource script MyExampleAssembly.res with the following statement:

(This gets run at the VS command prompt in the directory where you just exported your .NET component using the Type Library Exporter Utility)

```
IDR_TYPELIB1 typelib "MyExampleAssembly.tlb"
```

What is IDR_TYPELIB1?

Also, it's not working for me. I have tried running this and it doesn't compile. I get a message "'IDR_TYPELIB1' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Answer (score 1):

It is a macro that's normally auto-generated when you use the unmanaged resource editor.  Just use a constant, 1 is fine.  You are also using the wrong tool to compile the resource script by the sound of it, you must run rc.exe.  It translates your .rc file to a .res file that the C# compiler can use.

Embedding the type library is optional btw, it is not something that COM Automation requires.  It is not a very good idea to do this in a managed project since the .tlb is generated *after* building the project.  Instead of before, as happens in a native COM project.  You create it with regasm.exe, /tlb option or the tlbexp.exe utility.  Your client can do this too.

Comment: Thanks Hans. What is a macro? Where does it come from? I haven't gotten as far as compiling the resource script yet . . . I am trying to _create_ the resource script using the IDR_TYPELIB1 command (which is as you say a macro).

Comment: Macros are used in the C language.  It is a symbol that gets replaced by something else by the pre-processor.  In this case the resource number.